# Avoiding repeating characters through regEx

Tags: javascript, c#, regex

I have the following four RegEx pattern

```
  string strIMEIRegEx = "^[0-9]{15}$";
  string strIMEIRegExAlt = "^[a-fA-F0-9]{14}$";
  string strNameRegEx = "^[0-9A-Za-z ]{1,50}$";
  string strNameRegEx = @"^(a-z|A-Z|0-9)*[^$%^&*;:,<>?()\""\']*$";
```

### Issues

1. For `strIMEIRegEx`  and `strIMEIRegExAlt`  it allows repeating 0 having count 14 (for eg - 00000000000000) which I need to avoid .It shouldn't allow 0 at the beginning too.
2. For `strNameRegEx` and strNameRegEx`it allows any single character string (For E.g it accepts`"@","!","q","1"`) . This RegEx should allow alphanumeric (with/without allowed special characters)

I know I have to update the above RegEx with `(.)\1{"Number of repeating characters wants to avoid",}` but I am unable to figure out how to make this fix with above RegEx pattern.

Comment: Downvoter please explain the reason .

Comment: not the downvoter but could you explain the second condition? You the limited the second regex to accept at least one character. `1` is numeric. THen?

Comment: @AvinashRaj regarding strNameRegEx . It allows empty string also.Currently it allows "@" like string which i want to avoid by making it a alphanumeric(with/without allowed special characters) . Hope it clarifies . Please let me know bro if it needs further explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1 - For strIMEIRegEx  and strIMEIRegExAlt  it allows repeating 0 having count 14 (for eg - 00000000000000) which i need to avoid .

Use  a negative lookahead assertion at the start.

```
string strIMEIRegEx = "^(?!0+$)[1-9][0-9]{14}$";
string strIMEIRegExAlt = "^(?!0+$)[a-fA-F1-9][a-fA-F0-9]{13}$";
```

I'll update my answer for second case once the question get updated, since the current one is not clear.

Comment: Can you please update the RegEx , so that it won't allow 0 at the beginning .

Comment: check my update.. edit the question or ask any questions to the answerer as quick as possible.

Comment: regarding strNameRegEx . It allows empty string also.Currently it allows "@" like string which i want to avoid by making it a alphanumeric(with/without allowed special characters) . Hope it clarifies . Please let me know bro if it needs further explanation

Comment: try `string strNameRegEx = @"^[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?: [a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$"` . if it's not, then post valid and invalid matches for the second one.